# How to know if event was attached in run time

Tags: c#, eventhandler

I dynamically add and remove `TextChanged` event:

```
TextBox.TextChanged -= new System.EventHandler(this.textBox_TextChanged);
........
TextBox.TextChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.textBox_TextChanged);
```

How can I know at some moment if this event was attached or detached?

Comment: There is no way to do that.

Comment: you should wrap the add/remove in a function - then you can see when those are called.

Comment: An event event notification system. That meta.

Comment: One of the arguments why people like to use Rx ... :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Has an event handler already been added?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/136975/has-an-event-handler-already-been-added) Also [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/937181/c-sharp-pattern-to-prevent-an-event-handler-hooked-twice) but otoh also [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2697247/how-to-determine-if-an-event-is-already-subscribed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to determine if an event was *ever* attached or removed, particularly not from an event in a class *you didn't define*. An `event` defined in another class can only appear on the left side of an add/remove operation - attempting to do otherwise will result in the compiler telling you as much as an error.

If you want to know about this for some reason that can't be better suited otherwise, consider instead raising a flag when attaching this even handler, so that you can query said flag later.