# Is there any way to find whether event is already subscribed

Tags: c#, wpf

I am using controls in my WPF window, and based on user interaction, I have to subscribe different controls ValueChanged/VisibilityChanged events. Is there any to check whether event is already subscribed or not, so that I should not subscribe it again.

Actually I am looking for a best practice for event subscription so that an object can only subscribe an event of other object once only.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2697247/how-to-determine-if-an-event-is-already-subscribed?rq=1 should be exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: Or you can do it without setting up a ton of boooleans http://stackoverflow.com/questions/136975/has-an-event-handler-already-been-added

Answer (score 0):

If event variable is null, then there's no subscription for Event.